# The daedric boots are bugging out

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can use the atronach forge to transform ebony boots into daedric and I can pick them up after they spawn; however, they don't appear inside of my inventory. I have reloaded my save several times and done all that I could to fix it, but they refuse to appear inside my inventory. No matter what I do, I can't get daedric boots that come from that forge. Please help.

Comment: I'm giving up on trying the traditional way to get the boots are there any other recipes for daedric boots

Comment: You could forge them normally if you have smithing to at least 90 and the corresponding perk. Or use player.additem [id] 1.

Answer (score 2):

If they are truley not appearing in your inventory (sometimes I scroll right past items) then, (if on PC) use console commands
I think the commands you'll need are

help DaedricBoots 0, to find the id, I can't remember if it's 0, or 4, try all numbers between 0 and 5, if you have to, just google the id.

the use player.placeatme TheIdGoesHere

Comment: just use additem, why bother with placeatme